# GitHub Actions unable to load via SSH despite it appearing to work using ssh-access

Tags: github, ssh, github-actions, ssh-agent

I am working on a github action to runs tests on my PRs and pushes but I am having trouble ensuring that the tests are able to access my private repos.

I have tested the SSH credentials I am using locally and they 100% work.

https://github.com/webfactory/ssh-agent

Here is the SSH agent I am using.

and here is my github action

```
# This workflow will do a clean install of node dependencies, build the source code and run tests across different versions of node
# For more information see: https://help.github.com/actions/language-and-framework-guides/using-nodejs-with-github-actions

name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - master
      - release/*
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
      - release/*

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x, 12.x, 14.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.4.0
      with:
        ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}

    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm run build --if-present
    - run: npm test
```

It appears to be making no attempt to utilize the SSH keys that it is getting

[image]

Comment: I was able to determine that the line `- name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}` being dropped after the uses was making it act as though the uses were not being called.

Answer (score 0):

Since https://github.com/Tixpire/tixpire-server seems to be private, you will need to use a [PAT (personal access token)](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token) to access it.
See also [actions/checkout issue 95](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/95).

It is an HTTPS URL, so no amount of SSH keys will work: you would need an SSH URL for that (`git@github.com:Tixpire/tixpire-server`)